# KeyError: 'value' for sepal_length

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I'm facing `KeyError` error here
**File "C:\Users\ayush\Python\iris_server.py", line 11, in predict
predict_request=[[data["sepal_length"],data["sepal_width"],data["petal_length"],data["petal_width"]]]

KeyError: 'sepal_length'**
when I run my client side code which has hardcoded values of the data fields

Flask Server side:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import numpy as np
import pickle
import os
os.chdir('C:/Users/bhosl/Python')
model = pickle.load(open('iris_model','rb')) 
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/api',methods=['POST'])  
def predict():     
    data = request.get_json(force=True)     
    predict_request=[[data["sepal_length"],data["sepal_width"],data["petal_length"],data["petal_width"]]]     
    req=np.array(predict_request)    
    print(req)     
    prediction = model.predict(predict_request)     
    pred = prediction[0]     
    print(pred)     
    return jsonify(int(pred))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':          
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Client side

```
import requests
import json
r = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/api', json={
    "sepal_lenth":3.2,
    "sepal_width":7.3,
    "petal_length":4.5,
    "petal_width":2.1
})
print(r.json)
print(r.status_code)
```

while the client side gives
**<bound method Response.json of <Response [500]>>

500** as the output
so assuming the code isn't the problem here,
How can I fix this
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled **`sepal_length`** as `sepal_lenth` on the client side.

**KeyError** is caused by python not being able to find a key in the dictionary. In your case, it cannot find the key `sepal_length`. The `<Response [500]>` because your sever encountered an Internal Server Error(KeyError), returning the status code of 500.

This should work:

```
import requests
import json
r = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/api', json={
    "sepal_length":3.2,
    "sepal_width":7.3,
    "petal_length":4.5,
    "petal_width":2.1
})
print(r.json)
print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: Hi @AYUSH, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.